Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\keebid\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 1108
Hello i am working on project for my college assignment, I am using wordpress and theme template for the website. everything is fine until on the checkout page i got an error of
"Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\keebid\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 1108"
And here is the code
function wp_check_invalid_utf8( $text, $strip = false ) {
$text = (string) $text;

    if ( 0 === strlen( $text ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    
    // Store the site charset as a static to avoid multiple calls to get_option().
    static $is_utf8 = null;
    if ( ! isset( $is_utf8 ) ) {
        $is_utf8 = in_array( get_option( 'blog_charset' ), array( 'utf8', 'utf-8', 'UTF8', 'UTF-8' ), true );
    }
    if ( ! $is_utf8 ) {
        return $text;
    }
    
    // Check for support for utf8 in the installed PCRE library once and store the result in a static.
    static $utf8_pcre = null;
    if ( ! isset( $utf8_pcre ) ) {
        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.PHP.NoSilencedErrors.Discouraged
        $utf8_pcre = @preg_match( '/^./u', 'a' );
    }
    // We can't demand utf8 in the PCRE installation, so just return the string in those cases.
    if ( ! $utf8_pcre ) {
        return $text;
    }
    
    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.PHP.NoSilencedErrors.Discouraged -- preg_match fails when it encounters invalid UTF8 in $text.
    if ( 1 === @preg_match( '/^./us', $text ) ) {
        return $text;
    }
    
    // Attempt to strip the bad chars if requested (not recommended).
    if ( $strip && function_exists( 'iconv' ) ) {
        return iconv( 'utf-8', 'utf-8', $text );
    }
    
    return '';

}

I dont know how to fix it and i have been searching tutorials on the internet but none can solve my problem. Please help me
I tried to change it to implode instead of array but it does not work

Which line is 1108?

The line 1108 is
$text = (string) $text;

Where did you call the wp_check_invalid_utf8 function? Check what you're passing into it, because it seems you must be passing in an array instead of text

Is this a minimal [mcve]? Please remove all irrelevant code and make it simple for us to replicate your problem with sample input provided by you.
